Transforming from Hilbert space to Liouville space and vice versa
I am learning about Hilbert space and Liouville space; I am wondering how to convert from one space to other space (e.g from Hilbert space to Liouville space or vice versa).
Additionally, in some notation I found, $H_L=H⊗H^T$ where $H_L$ is the Hamiltonian in Liouville space, $H$ is the Hamiltonian in the Hilbert space;  $H^T$ is the transpose of $H$. $⊗$ is the Kronecker product.
In some other notation I found $H_L=H⊗I-I⊗H^T$ where $I$ is the identity matrix (here 4*4).
I am confused which one is the actual one for the transformation.

Is "Liouville space" the same thing as phase space?

… .

@flippiefanus no, the Liouville space is not same as phase space. Rather, Liouville space is sometimes called as line space as well.
